# How to mimic JavaScript's onBlur event in Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms, events

I have phone and email textboxes on a Windows Form that I want to validate when the user leaves the fields.

When I double click the textbox in Visual Studio form designer, it creates a `textchanged` event. This isn't quite suitable as want to call the validate method only when the user is done entering the full entry, not after every keystroke.

Is there a way to do this similar to `onBlur` event in JavaScript?

I have tried `MouseLeave`, `Off Focus`, and they all act like `TextChanged`.

How can this be done?

Comment: BTW, the C# language doesn't have `OnBlur` or anything like it. It's the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class of the .NET Framework which has them. The methods exist for any and all .NET languages.

Comment: @Charlie: the OP and many others don't seem to get the distinction between the language and the framework. You'd have trouble poking around in JavaScript to find onBlur, for instance.

Comment: I don't know if it's because of the way that Java is architected or not, but many people seem to think that the .NET Framework and C# are part of the same thing. I've been getting pedantic about it to help them better understand the answers they're going to get, most of which from people who know better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the `Leave` event. Navigate to the Property page for your control.

You can simply type the name of the method you'll be creating. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and Visual Studio will create the method for you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The Validating event was designed to do this.  Set e.Cancel = true if you're not happy with the input.  The ErrorProvider component is ideal to provide visual feedback.

Answer (score -1):

[OnLostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onlostfocus.aspx), maybe?

Answer (score -1):

There's an `OnLostFocus` event for controls. You should be able to use that.