# Calculating a total without using a click event C#

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator

I wrote a Windows Form Application calculator which takes square footage of specific parts of a home and estimates approximately how much it would cost to rebuild that structure.

I am using TextChanged events so that as the user types input it converts the square footage to the calculated rebuild cost.

```
public void txtBuiltInGarage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int outputValue = 0;
    bool isNumber = false;

    isNumber = int.TryParse(txtBuiltInGarage.Text, out outputValue);

    if (!isNumber)
    {
        txtBuiltInGarage.Text = "";
        txtBuiltInGarageCost.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        int builtinGarageSQ;
        int builtinGarageCostPerSF = 100;

        builtinGarageSQ = int.Parse(txtBuiltInGarage.Text.ToString());
        builtinGarageCost = builtinGarageSQ * builtinGarageCostPerSF;
        txtBuiltInGarageCost.Text = builtinGarageCost.ToString();
    }
}
```

However, I want this functionality to carry over to the total of all the fields. For examples, when the user enters 100 square feet for a built in garage, it will displayed the sum of 100 * 100 in the txtBuiltInGarageCost, but it will also display the total in the sum box and check it against the other value fields to see if any further calculation should be taking place. Basically, this application is a conversion of an earlier Excel Spreadsheet and I want to keep the "sum as you go along" feel to it. The problem with using a click event is that because some fields remain editable after the button is clicked I have to write a work around which I think detracts from the over all feel of a well written program. Here is what my code looks like when the user clicks the calculate button.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    totalRC = livingSpaceCost + builtinGarageCost + attachedGarageCost + deckCost + openPorchCost + enclosedPorchCost + additionalFeaturesCost;
    txtTotalReplacementCost.Text = totalRC.ToString();

    txtLivingSpace.ReadOnly = true;
    txtBuiltInGarage.ReadOnly = true;
    txtAttachedGarage.ReadOnly = true;
    txtDeck.ReadOnly = true;
    txtEnclosedPorch.ReadOnly = true;
    txtOpenPorch.ReadOnly = true;
    txtAdditionalFeaturesCost.ReadOnly = true;
    cmbConstructionQuality.Visible = false;
    lblConstructionQualityOutput.Visible = true;
    cmbConstructionType.Visible = false;
    lblConstructionTypeOutput.Visible = true;
    lblClearAlert.Visible = true;

    lblConstructionQualityOutput.Text = cmbConstructionQuality.SelectedItem.ToString();
    lblConstructionTypeOutput.Text = cmbConstructionType.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

So how can I make txtTotalReplacementCost automatically calculate as I input/change values in the other fields?

Comment: Data bind a `total` value to the field you wish to be updated

Comment: WPF / windows forms ? If you use WPF , you can use binding on each field/textbox you want , on every change ( on set method ) you'll run the "ShowResults()" method .

Comment: Sorry, always forget to include this... I'm using a Windows Form Application.

Comment: so if you use Windows Form , hmm .. I feel sorry for you :)

Comment: WPF's labels use `.Content`, that's how you can tell the difference.

Comment: At the end of all of the Text Changed handlers call a function that collects all of the fields and calculates a total value.

Comment: @Zakos - Winforms has data binding as well so you can still use it effectively, it just has a few bugs that don't exist in wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public double livingSpaceCost;
            public double builtinGarageCost;
            public double attachedGarageCost;
            public double deckCost;
            public double openPorchCost;
            public double enclosedPorchCost;
            public double additionalFeaturesCost;
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                livingSpaceCost = 0;
                builtinGarageCost = 0;
                attachedGarageCost = 0;
                deckCost = 0;
                openPorchCost = 0;
                enclosedPorchCost = 0;
                additionalFeaturesCost = 0;
            }
            void calctotalrc()
            {
                double total;
                total = livingSpaceCost + builtinGarageCost + attachedGarageCost + deckCost + openPorchCost + enclosedPorchCost + additionalFeaturesCost;
                txtTotalReplacementCost.Text = total.ToString();
            }

public void txtBuiltInGarage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int outputValue = 0;
        bool isNumber = false;

        isNumber = int.TryParse(txtBuiltInGarage.Text, out outputValue);

        if (!isNumber)
        {
            txtBuiltInGarage.Text = "";
            txtBuiltInGarageCost.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            int builtinGarageSQ;
            int builtinGarageCostPerSF = 100;

            builtinGarageSQ = int.Parse(txtBuiltInGarage.Text.ToString());
            builtinGarageCost = builtinGarageSQ * builtinGarageCostPerSF;
            txtBuiltInGarageCost.Text = builtinGarageCost.ToString();
        }
        calctotalrc();
    }
 }
```

call the calctotalrc method in all your text chage event.

Comment: Incorporating the calctotalrc method worked to resolve this issue. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the Leave event to trigger testing the data for valid input every time the user changes input boxes.

Leave can be used to mimic the JavaScript onblur event. See this answer also:
[How to mimic JavaScript's onBlur event in Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071636/how-to-mimic-javascripts-onblur-event-in-windows-forms)

You could also add "Enter" events to the textboxes, so that calculation dependent textboxes clear when a user begins to edit one of the textboxes on which the calculations depend.