# Handling of TextBox TextChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, textchanged

`TextChanged` event is called of `TextBox` whenever user type or assigned text in code.
Requirement is to not trigger this event whenever text assigned from code.
We have two ways to handle this change:

1. Use local variable to suppress this change
2. Bind/Unbind `TextChanged` event before and after text assigned to `Textbox`

Is there any best way to achieve this and avoid these two custom tricks?

Comment: [Take a look at this. mimic javascript onblur event in windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071636/how-to-mimic-javascripts-onblur-event-in-windows-forms)

Comment: There is no shame in using flags but I think I would use a SetText function that uses option 2.)

Comment: Another option is not to handle the `TextChanged` event directly and use the validation events (Validating/Validated) instead. Unless there's code that performs formatting on the fly. In this case, I would wire up the handlers of the TextBoxes that need this treatment only after their content has been initialized to the default values.